# ASP.Net MVC3 Viewbag - set to selected index of dropdownbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I'm totally new to MVC.  I would like to create a Viewbag to contain the selected index of the  control.  Can I set that within my .ascx file? or what would be the best way to capture this information?

```
<select id="accounttype" style="float: left;" autocomplete="off">
                <% 
                    if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToUpper().StartsWith("/COMMERCIAL")) //Commercial
                    {
                %>
                <option value="C" selected="selected">eManager+</option>
                <option value="C">Retirement Plans</option>
                <option value="C">Brokerage Accounts</option>
                <%
                    }
                    else if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToUpper().StartsWith("/BUSINESS")) //Business
                    {
                %>
                <option value="B" selected="selected">eManager+</option>
                <option value="B">Business Credit Card</option>
                <option value="B">Retirement Plans</option>
                <option value="B">Brokerage Accounts</option>
                <%
                    }
                    else //Personal, root or other
                    {
                %>
                <option value="P" selected="selected">Online Banking</option>
                <option value="P">Health Savings Account</option>
                <option value="P">Paychek Plus!&reg;</option>
                <option value="P">Gift Cards</option>
                <option value="P">Business Tax Manager</option>
                <option value="P">Business Card Manager</option>
                <option value="P">Business Credit Card</option>
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing things the hard way.  In your controller do this:

```
if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToUpper().StartsWith("/COMMERCIAL")) //Commercial 
{ 
    ViewBag.ListContents = new SelectList(new[] {new {name = "eManager+", value="C"},
       {name = "Retirement Plans", value="C"},
       {name = "Brokerage Accounts", value="C"}}, "value", "name");
}
// similar for your other if statements as well

ViewBag.DropDownID = selectedvalue;

return View();
```

then in your view

```
<% Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DropDownID, ViewBag.ListContents); %>
```

The problem, however is that since you have multiple entries with the same value, you can only select the first one in code.  You would be better to give them each unique values then on post determine which values are for each category.

For example, set that values to "C1" "C2" "C3" and then you can check if the string starts with C rather than equals C

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a form in there.  Set the ViewBag in the controller's action code after you post the form.